# Android- Parsing Local JSON Data (assets folder)

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am making a test app with Android. I have a json file and i want to read it into activity class. Here is the json file. Wrote the code but the code doesn't recognize "question" variable i described upside.

```html
{
    "questions": [
        {
                "id": "a200",
                "question": "lorem ipsum dolor _______ amet",
                "optionA": "lorem",
                "optionB": "ipsum",
                "optionC" : "dolor",
                "optionD": "sit"
                "rightAnswer" : "sit"
                    
        },
        {
                "id": "b200",
                "question": "_____ ipsum dolor sit amet",
                "optionA": "lorem",
                "optionB": "ipsum",
                "optionC" : "dolor",
                "optionD": "sit"
                "rightAnswer" : "lorem"
                    
        },
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "question": "lorem _____ dolor sit amet",
                "optionA": "lorem",
                "optionB": "ipsum",
                "optionC" : "dolor",
                "optionD": "sit"
                "rightAnswer" : "ipsum"                    
        },
  ]
}
```

And here is my QuizActivityAdjectives.java file's onCreate part.

```html
public class QuizActivityAdjectives extends Activity {

 TextView txt_questionAdjective;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_adjectives);
  // Hangi xml dosyasının dikkate alınacağı belirlendi.

  // Reading json file from assets folder
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  BufferedReader br = null;
  try {
   br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
     "Questions.json")));
   String temp;
   while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
    sb.append(temp);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   try {
    br.close(); // stop reading
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  // Try to parse JSON
  try {
   // Creating JSONObject from String
   JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject();

   // Creating JSONArray from JSONObject
   JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObjMain.getJSONArray("questions");

   // JSONArray has four JSONObject
   for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    // Creating JSONObject from JSONArray
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    // Getting data from individual JSONObject
    int id = jsonObj.getInt("id");
    String question = jsonObj.getString("question");
    String optionA = jsonObj.getString("optionA");
    String optionB = jsonObj.getString("optionB");
    String optionC = jsonObj.getString("optionC");
    String optionD = jsonObj.getString("optionD");
    String rightAnswer = jsonObj.getString("rightAnswer");

   }

  } catch (JSONException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  String myjsonstring = sb.toString();

  txt_questionAdjective = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_questionAdjective);
  txt_questionAdjective.setText(question); //THE CODE ERRORS HERE. CAN NOT RESOLVE QUESTION VARIABLE.

 }
```

How can i get rid of that matter? And is the code this way making any sense? Will it work ?

The error : "question cannot be resolved to a variable" (The comment line i wrote at the bottom)

---

**EDIT:SOLVED** I wouldn't ever expect but after correcting json file (there should've been a comma which i'ven't noticed, i was gotta change the id value which have been described as int and given in the json file with a char (like a200). After that the problem was gone and the json was fetched.

Comment: try creating the `JSONObject` with the `String` you read, instead of just marking it with a comment :P

Comment: cant ask Will it work? Do some work and report error if any occurs.

Comment: As i mentioned in the snippet at comment line..

Description Resource Path Location Type
question cannot be resolved to a variable QuizActivityAdjectives.java /YDSQuizApplication/src/org/example/ydsquizapp line 79 Java Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new JSONObject, instead of parsing your file:

```
JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject();
```

should be:

```
JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
```

**Edit:**

Now I understood your question.

You are out of scope and variable `question` doesn't exist anymore. **Furthermore** there are **multiple questions**, how do you expect to set it to your `TextView`?

You can save questions into an array and use any of them like this:

```
List<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        ...
        questions.add(jsonObj.getString("question"));
        ...
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String myjsonstring = sb.toString();

// Check if questions have been fetched
if (questions.size() > 0) {
    txt_questionAdjective = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_questionAdjective);
    // Use the first question
    txt_questionAdjective.setText(questions.get(0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So what is the damn reason it gives me error that question cannot be resolved to a variable?

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
question cannot be resolved to a variable QuizActivityAdjectives.java /YDSQuizApplication/src/org/example/ydsquizapp line 79 Java Problem

Comment: @nsarchar update your question with the error please. Can't read it via a comment.

Comment: Unfortunately seems not fetching. No text displays. Even when i write a random text inside the setText like       txt_questionAdjective.setText("lorem ipsum dolor _______ amet");
it doesn't appear which means the code doesn't enter inside the if block. So the size is not > 0.

Comment: @nsarchar then check if you enter the json array loop and even if you get the json string right.